# Designing UI for android phone

Tags: android, user-interface, screen-resolution

I am developing an android app. My client has got Motorola Atrix. I designed the ui in eclipse based on screen size 3.7in WVGA (Nexus One). Which works fine in almost all devices like HTC desire, galaxys2... but on Motorola Atrix (540 x 960 pixels) its showing some blank space on bottom.

How can I target an UI for that device?

I have already read in android developer t[utorials](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html#AlternativeResources) but didnt get an idea.

Here is the current layout

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:id="@+id/ScrollView01"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent">
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:background="#FFFFFF" android:layout_height="525dp">
</RelativeLayout>
```

how can I do this properly?
Thanks

Comment: It might be the problem in the layour I guess, you have to set the layout in the way that it fill the UI completely.

Comment: if you show a part of your code, it would be easier to tell you what you have to change to make it fit

Comment: I have added the layout file. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved the issue by adding option `android:fillViewport="true"` in scrollview properties.
Thanks all.